# Angular View Component Data Loss during Reload Refresh using BehaviorSubject

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular9, angular-local-storage

I am writing an Angular9 app with a use case where I am buffering data across 3 pages (with forms taking data input).

Then, on the 4th page, I display a summary of the details gathered across the 3 pages as read only text.

I have implemented the data buffering using the following article:

https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/infragistics/posts/simplest-way-to-share-data-between-two-unrelated-components-in-angular

Which uses the BehaviorSubject

Below is my data service logic:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, throwError } from 'rxjs';
    import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { UserResponse } from  './user-response';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })

    export class UserService {

        //Details Page 1
        public salutation: BehaviorSubject<string>;
        public firstName: BehaviorSubject<string>;

      // Base url
      baseurl = 'https://localhost:8080/rest';

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      // Http Headers
      httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
      }

      // POST
      createUser(data): Observable<UserResponse> {
        alert('user - details = '+ data);
        return this.http.post<UserResponse>(this.baseurl + '/user', JSON.stringify(data), this.httpOptions)
        .pipe(
          retry(1),
          catchError(this.errorHandler)
        )
      }

      // Error handling
      errorHandler(error) {
         let errorMessage = '';
         if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
           // Get client-side error
           errorMessage = error.error.message;
         } else {
           // Get server-side error
           errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
         }
         console.log(errorMessage);
         return throwError(errorMessage);
      }

}
```

Below is my first view component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserService } from '../service/user.service';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details1',
  templateUrl: './details1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details1.component.css']
})
export class Details1Component implements OnInit {
  salutation: string;
  firstName: string;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  goToDetails2(form : NgForm) {
          this.userService.salutation = new BehaviorSubject(form.value.salutation);
          this.userService.firstName = new BehaviorSubject(form.value.firstName);
      }

}
```

Below is a snippet of my final/summary view component

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../service/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-summary',
  templateUrl: './summary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./summary.component.css']
})

export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit {

       salutation: string;
       firstName: string;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    public userService: UserService
  ) {
   }

   ngOnInit(): void {
       this.userService.salutation.subscribe(c => { this.salutation = c; });
       this.userService.firstName.subscribe(c => { this.firstName = c; });
   }

}
```

On the final page my html excerpts is as follows:

```
<form #detailsForm4="ngForm">
<div class="govuk-form-group">
  <table class="govuk-table">
    <thead class="govuk-table__head">
    <tr class="govuk-table__row"></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="govuk-table__body" align="left">
    <tr class="govuk-table__row">
      <th scope="row" class="govuk-table__header">Salutation</th>
      <td class="govuk-table__cell">   {{salutation}} </td>
      <td class="govuk-table__cell"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="govuk-table__row">
      <th scope="row" class="govuk-table__header">First name</th>
      <td class="govuk-table__cell">   {{firstName}} </td>
      <td class="govuk-table__cell"> </td>
    </tr>
```

The data is displayed on the summary page as captured on the forms in pages 1-3, 
BUT the data is lost on page refresh or when my machine hibernates etc

I have read about local and session storage persistence and used it since the angularjs 1.x days.
Ages ago, I was actually surprised when the data disappeared on my summary screen!

I guess that an ideal solution will involve storing the data in client side storage when the user navigates away from the relevant form, then retrieving the data on the summary page.

I guess, when the summary page is refreshed or displayed for the first time, 
I will check storage for the data and display if it exist.
If storage is empty, then I will be using data from previous page at runtime.

Please, I need help with a best practice and stable solution, which is cross browser friendly and intelligent for a commercial application.

Also, an approach that fits into Angular9 BehaviorSubject - rxjs stack OR Any recent features, because I know Angular has evolved since AngularJs 1.x ?

The summary details is only changed when the user navigates back to any of the pages 1-3 to change the form details.

I will appreciate any code snippet or reference to keep the data on the summary page.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Seems to be obvious that data is lost in case of refresh. One of the solution is to keep you data in the local storage or if that is not input which come from the user get it again from server after refresh.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan for your quick reply. I could not find a good snippet on the use of local storage, that fits into angular9. Wanted a re-assurance of best practice pattern etc

Comment: This is most likely an issue with the UserService being reloaded when not expected.  To prove that in ngOnInit log a message to the console.  Then recreate the issue. If you see more than one message....you can consider making the behaviorsubjects static which puts a bit more work into ensuring the content is always the proper content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will propose you to use localStorage within your `SummaryComponent` within ngOnDestroy lifecycle hook. It will always set your data within localStorage before component will be destroyed due to refresh. Then when you are trying to retrieve data from the service, if it will be empty try to get it from localStorage.

```
export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

   salutation: string;
   firstName: string;

constructor(
  private router: Router,
  public userService: UserService
) {
  }

 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.userService.salutation.subscribe(c => { this.salutation = c || localStorage.get('salutation'); });
   this.userService.firstName.subscribe(c => { this.firstName = c || localStorage.get('firstName'); });
 }

 ngOnDestroy(): void {
   localStorage.setItem('salutation', this.salutation));
   localStorage.setItem('firstName', this.firstName));
 }

}
```

Similar implementation you can do in the component where this values are set and you expect that user can refresh the page before go to the next page.

EDIT

Sorry, you are right that ngOnDestory will not trigger on page refresh to do that you will need to handle window:beforeunload.

```
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  beforeunload($event: Event): void {
   // set localStorage here
  }
```

Going forward with your solution, the best option to set items to the localStorage is the place where you set values to the service. It's probably **goToDetails2** method.

```
goToDetails2(form : NgForm) {
          this.userService.salutation = new BehaviorSubject(form.value.salutation);
          this.userService.firstName = new BehaviorSubject(form.value.firstName);
          localStorage.setItem('salutation', form.value.salutation));
          localStorage.setItem('firstName', form.value.firstName));
      }
```

EDIT-2 to your problem described in the comment

I will propose you to initialize your **BehaviorSubject** directly inside of the service.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UserService {

    //Details Page 1
    public salutation: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');
    public firstName: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');
```

And then within your **Details1Component** set values on them using next

```
goToDetails2(form : NgForm) {
          this.userService.salutation.next(form.value.salutation);
          this.userService.firstName.next(form.value.firstName);
          localStorage.setItem('salutation', form.value.salutation));
          localStorage.setItem('firstName', form.value.firstName));
      }
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, Had a go see outcomes:
1) ngOnDestroy() is not called on refresh, but when i click the browser back button w chrome.So, salutation.subscribe(c => { this.salutation = c || localStorage.getItem('salutation'); }) does not work on refresh (2) added logic localStorage.setItem('salutation', this.salutation)); in page1 component. Then user fills form and goes to summary page. Alert() on 1st line of ngOnInit in summary page confirms the data is retrieved from localstrorage, but salutation.subscribe(c => { this.salutation = c || localStorage.get('salutation'); }) does not display of data.

Comment: Setting the data in the page 1 components makes the data available in summary page using localStorage.getItem(). But, after refresh, the salutation.subscribe(c => { this.salutation = c || localStorage.get('salutation'); }); Does Not Work. It appears refresh removes what has been previously published.

Comment: Could you add console.log(localStorage.get('salutation')) whin your subscription, when you got an entire way from the first step to the summary and then refresh the page? Also you can take look at what is set in your localStorage using browser dev tools.

Comment: Good morning Stefan, getting error in console. TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at SummaryComponent.ngOnInit (summary.component.ts:67)
Problem is after refresh this.userService.salutation is undefined.
Looks like the data service variables needs to be re-initialised after page refresh. In summary component, I have defined a var underfined; and then checked       if(this.userService.salutation==undefined){ this.userService= new UserService(..). But UserService has constructor(private http: HttpClient) Looks messy. What do you suggest? Do I need to re-init service

Comment: Thanks for your comment and edited post. I think, I am setting the variables successfully in local storage. 
Problem is that UserService variable is showing as undefined as described above. Do I need to re-initialize the service? 
How is it best done with the HttpClient argument?
Is this a good approach?

Comment: Hi, even after i manually initialised data service variables in the summary component as follows:  

var undefined;
        if(this.userService.salutation==undefined){
          this.userService.salutation = new BehaviorSubject(localStorage.getItem('salutation'));
          this.userService.firstName = new BehaviorSubject(localStorage.getItem('firstName'));
        }

The form fields were not populated. So, it appears I have 2 problems:
1. Initialising the service on refresh 2.Populating the page fields via subscribe, which reads from local storage.The local storage has relevant data

Comment: Wow! Stefan. Thank you so much.
Initializing my BehaviorSubject directly inside of the service did the trick.
I must confess I have not got my head round the RxJs, Behaviour and How it relates to Angular. I knew about it in the last few days through the blog https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/infragistics/posts/simplest-way-to-share-data-between-two-unrelated-components-in-angular, when trying to share data across my views in angular9. 
Stefan! I will not mind a good and practical primer reference from you.
Stay safe and well broz!

Comment: My next challenge is a Https POST restful API call via angular, using an OAuth2 Authorization Token..
I got it working via postman using an OAuth2 Authorization Token, just to make sure I have a working json request payload and functional API.
Now, I need to replicate that in the same angular app, i.e. posting the details compiled across the 3 pages to the service with the OAuth2 Token header. 
Please, watch the space and any tips/ref will be appreciated as well. Thanks.